Find entire list of most common values in a range?
I'm working on a Google Sheet that will include rows where people give a number rating then include text. I want to have a column where I read the rows, parse them into the number and text, then write out the average of the numbers & a list of all the most common text values.
Example:



Column A
Column B
Average




1 Cool text
2 Uncool text
1.5 Cool text, Uncool text


8 Cool text
4 Cool text
6 Cool text


1.5 Cool

1.5 Cool



and so on
I'm having issues with the MODE function, though.
In the case of row 1 above, I get the error MODE cannot produce a result. No values occur more than once.. I tried using REPT and manually doing a repeat to effectively duplicate all of the values, but I still get the same error:
=MODE.MULT(FLATTEN({(FILTER(A2:B2,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:B2))));(FILTER(A2:B2,NOT(ISBLANK(A2:B2))))}))

I also have not figured out how to display the entire list in one cell once I have it

list of all the most common text values.. how many?

Finding the value with most occurrences:
I do think that there is an on going issue with Mode Function that doesn't let it return a string Value, it only works on Int. I have created a Formula that can do both of your expected output.
Try this formula
=LET(c, A1:B1,z,TOCOL(SPLIT(JOIN(" ", c)," ")), y,REDUCE(0,z,LAMBDA(a,r, IF(ISNUMBER(r), SUM(a,r),a))), JOIN("",y/COUNTA(c),CHOOSECOLS(LET(w, LET(x, TOCOL(SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(",",c),"[.]",""),"[0-9]",""),",")), y, unique(x), z, BYROW(y, lambda(r,COUNTA(FILTER(x, x=r)))), HSTACK(y,z)), FILTER(w,CHOOSECOLS(w,2)=MAX(w))),1)))

Sample Output


Note: This is not on a dynamic spilling function, though you can easily implement that by changing the first value on the range. Feel free to ask any questions if you have one.

References:
Reduce
Filter

Thanks a ton! This almost suits my needs exactly, there were a few issues I encountered. I only want to average the first number in the cells, e.g if A1 in my example was "1 Cool text 2" it shouldn't impact the average. I think there is a way to do this with LEFT or REGEXEXTRACT but I couldn't figure it out. I also surrounded the entire thing with an IFERROR(..., "") to protect against empty cells causing a div by 0 error and modified the SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE segment to this SPLIT(REGEXREPLACE(JOIN(",",c),"(^|)[0-9|.]+",""),",") so that numbers inside each line wouldn't also get cut out

This answer relies on a combination of modern and old-school techniques.
Try this formula in Cell C1:
=map(A2:A4,B2:B4,
 lambda(cola,colb,
   if(
     iferror(right(cola,len(cola)-len(iferror(index(SPLIT(cola, " "), 0, 1)))-1))=iferror(right(colb,len(colb)-len(iferror(index(SPLIT(colb, " "), 0, 1)))-1)),
       average(iferror(index(SPLIT(cola, " "), 0, 1)),iferror(index(SPLIT(colb, " "), 0, 1)))&" "&iferror(right(cola,len(cola)-len(iferror(index(SPLIT(cola, " "), 0, 1)))-1)),average(iferror(index(SPLIT(cola, " "), 0, 1)),iferror(index(SPLIT(colb, " "), 0, 1)))&" "&textjoin(", ",true,iferror(right(cola,len(cola)-len(iferror(index(SPLIT(cola, " "), 0, 1)))-1)),iferror(right(colb,len(colb)-len(iferror(index(SPLIT(colb, " "), 0, 1)))-1)))
   )
 )
)


Logic

the formula relies on MAP(array1, [array2, ...], LAMBDA)

"array1" = Column A
"array2" = Column B
`"LAMBDA" works as follows:

index(SPLIT(A2, " "), 0, 1) - returns the first element (the number value) in Column A; ditto for Column B
average is used to get the average of values in Column A & B
right(A2,len(A2)-len(index(SPLIT(A2, " "), 0, 1))-1) - returns the text element for Column A; ditto Column B
test for "Column A text"="Column B text"

if yes, display the `average&" "&Column A text,
if no, display average&" "&textjoin(", ",true,Column A text,Column B text))`




add a bunch of iferror




Output


This works with less modification than the other solution for the example but I'm wondering how I would add support for more columns?

how I would add support for more columns? In terms of this answer, you are raising a non-trivial issue. The answer addresses the question that was asked. If you want to support more columns, then I suggest you post a new question.
